# combobox event & clear method

Tags: c#, winforms, window

```
   private void ComboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear();
        XmlNodeList node_lst = doc["paths"].ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode item in node_lst)
        {
            if (item.InnerText.Contains(ComboBox1.Text))
            {
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(item.InnerText);
            }
        }            
    }
```

I am new in this website, i have question in this event when I clear items from combobox, I get these items from an xml file; my problem is when I  enter letters in combobox text, the text is entered in inversed way, I expected that the problem in clear method but i have not idea how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ' Text is entered in the inversed way', please? Do you mean it appears from right to left?

Comment: try creating a string then insert the string to the combobox

Comment: You have debug it? Are you sure the item are you read from xml is not a single char?

Comment: thanks for every one i make                                comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length;                                it run correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete all items from the `ComboBox` the cursor will be set to the first position., So after each character that you type the cursor will be shifted to the left and you get the feeling of typing from right to left.

The solution would be to set the `SelectionStart` after the for-loop by hand to the end of the `Text`:

```
comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var nodeList = node_lst.Cast<XmlNode>()
                               .Select(x => library.GetMemberName(int.Parse(x.InnerText)))
                               .ToList();
nodeList.Reverse();
```

More info on `Reverse()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for you i try                                                                                                    comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length;                                             it run correctly